# Many to one and Many to many on same objects using datamapper ORM in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I have an application that requires:

user owns many projects.
project has one owner.

user works on many projects.
projects have many users.

so I have 3 tables, users, projects_users, projects.
The relationships are:

one user (owner) --- many projects (created_by)

many users (id) ---- via projects_users (user_id, project_id) ---- many projects (id).

In Codeigniter I've set up the following relationships in the datamapper models:

```
Class Project extends DataMapper {

var $has_one = array(
    'created_by' => array(
        'class' => 'user',
        'other_field' => 'owns'
    )
);
var $has_many = array('user' => array(
        'class' => 'user',
        'other_field' => 'project',
        'join_table' => 'projects_users'));
```

and...

```
    class User extends DataMapper {

var $has_many = array(
    'project' => array(
        'class' => 'project',
        'other_field' => 'user',
        'join_table' => 'projects_users'
    ),
    'owns' => array(
        'class' => 'project',
        'other_field' => 'created_by'
    )
);
```

This doesn't seem to work however and I get a recursive error. 
What is the correct way to represent this relationship in datamapper?

Comment: right - I see, my 'other' fields are not reciprocal. A result of staring at code too long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at **Multiple Relationships to the Same Model** on the doc page: http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html

I'm guessing something like this:

```
class Project extends DataMapper {
    $has_one = array(
        'owner' => array(
            'class' => 'user',
            'other_field' => 'owned_project'
        )
    );
    $has_many = array(
        'user' => array(
            'class' => 'user',
            'other_field' => 'user_project'
        )
    );
}

class User extends DataMapper {
    $has_many = array(
        'owned_project' => array(
            'class' => 'project',
            'other_field' => 'owner'
        ),
        'user_project' => array(
            'class' => 'project',
            'other_field' => 'user'
        )
    );
}
```

and you would access like this:

```
$project = new Project(1); // where "1" is the ID of the project
$owner = $project->owner->get();
$project_users = $project->user->get();

// -------------------------------

$me = new User(1); // where "1" is the ID of the user
$my_projects = $me->owned_project->get();
```

**UPDATE**

You will need to update your `projects_users` join table to this:

```
projects_users
--------------
user_id
owner_id
owned_project_id
user_project_id
```

Note that these all match the "keys" that you declared in your `$has_one` and `$has_many` arrays. **You will not need to update the `users` or `projects` tables (the only requirement is that each of them have a primary key field named "id")**.

Comment: What you're suggesting is a one-to-one and a many-to-many. I want a one-to-many and a many-to-many.

Comment: I've edited this (not sure if it was before your comment). Here's the explanation:  `Project has one owner.` `Project has many users.` `User has many owned projects.` `User has many projects.` -- So there's a 1 to many on owner -> project. There's a many to many on user -> project.

Comment: Hi, I must have commented first. At first glance, mine and yours don't seem too dissimilar. I'll have a good look. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: So, this is where my confusion lies: I want to use the id field in the users table as the 'owner' identity. In your solution is the 'owned_project' field just a key defined in datamapper or does it map to a field in the database - the implication being I need another join table?

Comment: The 'owned_project' is just a key. You only need the one join table. However, you need to add additional fields to it. I forgot that part. When I get to the office, I'll add that part to the answer.

Comment: I've just updated the answer to indicate changes to the join table. Let me know if you have any problems with this.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't tried that. It makes sense. I'll have a go when I get back onto it.